# Проблемы с мультиплеером

Tags: java, android

Объясните, пожалуйста, кто-нибудь как устроен WiFi мультиплеер в приложениях.

В интернете полно туториалов на эту тему. Например, с multicast DNS очень просто  подключить 2 устройства в одной локальной сети. Но выходит, что и клиент и сервер уже должны быть подключены к какой-то сети (то есть нужно еще какое-то устройство, которое раздавало бы эту сеть). Если сервер включит режим модема, то он уже не сможет подключиться своей же сети и, следовательно, уже ничего не работает.

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться.

Comment: два андроид устройства, при подключении по wifi организуется только локальная сеть(интернета не предусматривается, интернет это как доп возможность). Требуется будет просканировать определенные ипы в сети локальной на предмет порта, порт найден? ответ есть? это сервер, подключаемся к нему.

Comment: JmDNS автоматически сканирует все ip в сети. Если одно устройство будет раздавать wifi, то оно уже не определяется, а если подключится например к wifi сети моего роутера, то оба устройства находят друг друга

Comment: если устройство "раздаёт wifi" - оно продолжает иметь доступ к каналу связи, и может передавать в него данные. Посмотрите в сторону WiFi Direct и примера его использования в SuperBeam.

Comment: И вот тема про передачу данных по WiFi: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345155/android-receive-and-send-data-through-wifi-connection-to-hardware

Comment: Wi-Fi peer-to-peer (P2P) доступен в Android 4.0 (API level 14) или старше. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html

Comment: @DimXenon, WiFi p2p даже не рассматривается, из-за высокого api. Нужна поддержка api 9

Comment: @DimXenon, а насчет ссылки на so, то там идет речь о том, что устройства будут подключены к одному роутеру, что не соответствует исходному условию

Comment: ну тогда вариант-извращение: попеременное создание WiFi сети на устройствах с именем, включающим некоторый токен для распознания устройствами и с блоком данных в названии сети, в котором кодировать передаваемые данные.) Устройства постоянно ищут сеть с именем, содержащим токен, забирают строку имени сети, парсят, после чего сами шарят сеть с именем-ответом. =) Не секьюрно и не очень-то и быстро, топорно, но можно реализовать.

Comment: @DimXenon, спасибо, но я не извращенец. Как-то же это сделано например в Minecraft PE или в Share it. Я думаю нужно сделать какой-то кастомный роутер или искать способ как перехватывать данные с точки доступа. Возможно есть еще более простые способы, но я ничего такого не нашёл в интернете

Comment: Перехват данных с точки доступа, как я думаю, не проблема. Цель - послать свои данные в канал связи, будучи раздающим устройством. А так - создали сеть, MAC у раздающего и у получающего есть - готовые уникальные идентификаторы, привязываете ID игрока в текущей игровой сессии к его маку, и дальше ведём обмен данными. Я думаю, нужно посмотреть реализацию P2P библиотек для поздних API и по возможности, создать свой велосипед на их основе.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю это ещё кому-то пригодиться.
Мне удалось подключиться к точке доступа без jmDNS используя адрес

```
192.168.43.1:8988
```

Через `ServerSocket/Socket`